# как при наведении курсора на кнопку сделать появления справки Windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Будет кнопка, и если удержать на этой кнопке мышку секунду где-то 0.5 будет появляться окно с текстом.

Comment: Стандартный `ToolTip` не подходит?

Comment: Благодарю) Очень подходит, но я всё таки думал использовать MouseEnter или MouseHover. Можете подсказать с этими?

Comment: Не, там будет целая куча проблем. Ну и я с WinForms не особо близок

Comment: оформите ответ с Тултипом) нужно зачесть вам его

Comment: Не надо имитировать ToolTip самостоятельно,если нет острого желания близко знакомиться с WinAPI. Если не хватает функциональности стандартного, лучше унаследоваться от него и добавить недостающее.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого есть штатные средства всплывающих подсказок. Смотрите [класс `ToolTip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip(v=vs.110).aspx)

Пример использования:

```
var myToolTip = new ToolTip();
myToolTip.SetToolTip(myButton, "ToolTip");
```